# what could be reasons for for corrupt sstables in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

i've been reading about "nodetool scrub" and "sccrubsstable" in order to repair corrupt sstables.  why and when do sstables get corrupted in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common I've seen is running out of disk space half way through writing. There is also cosmic rays flipping bits on disk and hardware failure. Occasionally you may find a bug in the Cassandra as well.